# How to change color of tab menu's left border?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a website here http://www.carantina.com/

When I move my mouse over 'URUNLER', you see tabbed menus. On the list, when a tab is active, there is a red color appears. I couldn't find how to change that color to blue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the class that is applying a red border to your tabs:

```
.z-tabs.vertical.top-left.white.z-bordered > ul.z-tabs-nav.z-tabs-desktop > li.z-active > a.z-link {
border-left: 3px solid #365BD1;
}
```

Search zozo.tabs.min.css for `border-left: 3px solid #365BD1;` and you should find it.

This is the parent tabs color: `#477390;`

Change this line: `border-left: 3px solid #365BD1;`

To this line: `border-left: 3px solid #477390;`

Answer (score 0):

(Using IE)

F12 => Select element by click => click the active tab => Traced Styles => border-left

Clearly shows that it is defined in zozo.tabs.min.css in the following selector:

```
.z-bordered.white.top-left.vertical.z-tabs>ul.z-tabs-desktop.z-tabs-nav>li.z-active>a.z-link
```

Answer (score 0):

In this location css:
http://www.carantina.com/css/zozo.tabs.min.css

line number:10

```
.z-tabs.vertical.top-left.white.z-bordered > ul.z-tabs-nav.z-tabs-desktop > li.z-active > a.z-link {
  border-left: 3px solid #477390;
}
```

edit this code